# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Chess Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **June 3** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on June 3, users can [nominate themselves](https://chess.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On June 10, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on June 18.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

So, I don't have a ton of rep on this site, but I have some good answers (IMO), and I have 3000+ rep on Puzzling.SE, so I'm familiar with moderation tools. Would I be a reasonably good candidate? I've heard that mods need to spend at least 30 mins/day working on the site; could I do 4-5 hrs across 3 days, or would I need to be active every day?

Just weighing the pros and cons of self-nominating before the nomination starts.

Comment: On this site, I don't imagine there's so much work you'd need to spend anything like 30 minutes a day. The more critical thing from my perspective is that there are moderators checking in (and handling any flags that might be around) a few times a week. If you already visit regularly, it won't be very different to be a moderator most of the time.

Comment: @JonEricson I appreciate the feedback. I might just give this a shot.

Comment: Yes, I believe you would make a fine candidate. You've got a fair amount of rep now, and seem to have quite a bit of moderation experience and familiarity with this community. If you feel comfortable being a mod, then you should absolutely nominate yourself.